# make a specific file only accessable?

Tags: php, .htaccess

how can i show only the index.php and ignore any other calls to other php files, so if i were to go to somefile.php, the page would stay at index.php all the time, however if i were to go to index.php?get=somefile it would then allow you to execute that.

so in short i only want the index.php to be the main caller and executor of everything and to ignore any calls to any other php files that is not index.php, i **dont want** the index.php to execute php files like `index.php?get=somefile.php` but instead use the `$_GET` varable it recieves from `index.php?get=somefile` and then use that later to include the file internally inside index.php

i have this in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

it does everything i'm asking for but it dosen't let you use get in index.php like index.php?get=somefile

where is it going wrong and how do i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index).*)\.php$ index.php?get=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```